# Customize font for tikzposter block title

Tags: tikzposter

What is the best way to customize the font style (e.g., use sans serif or bold or a different font than the text) for the title of a block in `tikzposter`?

I can't find any option in the documentation, even with `\defineblockstyle`. Unless I  can alter the font style for the `blocktitle` tikz node?

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Pinco Pallino}
\institute{Boh}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{How to make this sans serif?}{
\lipsum
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the block like this:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Pinco Pallino}
\institute{Boh}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\block}{\bf\LARGE\color{blocktitlefgcolor}}{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE\color{blocktitlefgcolor}}{}{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{How to make this sans serif?}{
\lipsum
}
\end{document}
```

[image]